# Work with Android Library GreenDroid

Tags: android, android-manifest

I want to use the [GreenDroid](https://github.com/cyrilmottier/GreenDroid) library in my application.
I added it as a library in the project settings.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.korn.tvbrain"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
          android:theme="@style/Theme.GreenDroid"
          android:name=".TVBrainApplication">>
        <activity
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:name=".TVBrainActivity" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

TVBrainActivity:

```
public class TVBrainActivity extends GDActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setActionBarContentView(R.layout.gd_action_bar_empty);
    }
}
```

Application Class:

```
public class AppBrainApplication extends GDApplication{

    @Override
    public Class<?> getHomeActivityClass() {
        return AppBrainApplication.class;
    }   

}
```

Error Log:

```
10-24 10:25:55.265: E/AndroidRuntime(524): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application com.korn.tvbrain.TVBrainApplication: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.korn.tvbrain.TVBrainApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bfd908
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:523)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3996)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2900(ActivityThread.java:119)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1901)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.korn.tvbrain.TVBrainApplication in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader@44bfd908
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:942)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  at android.app.ActivityThread$PackageInfo.makeApplication(ActivityThread.java:518)
10-24 10:25:55.295: E/AndroidRuntime(524):  ... 11 more
```

I always get a ClassNotFound Exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In application tag in AndroidManifest file I guess `android:name=".TVBrainApplication"` here the name should be `android:name=".AppBrainApplication"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you should add `android:name=".AppBrainApplication"` instead of `android:name=".TVBrainApplication"` in your AndroidManifest

Comment: Is Lalit's answer different than your?

Comment: No, it's not, it seems like he answered just a millisecond before me.